# Why does the enum can only read the top case?

Tags: swift, xcode, enums

I have a navigation tab bar and each tab contains a picture of array, see picture below. My question is. Why does the enum only see the top case "mens", it doesn't switch to women, arts and saved. I tried to delete the case mens, then it can only see the case "women", whatever is on top, thats only thing cellForItemAtIndexPath can see. Everything is already connected I tried to get them one by one to see if they're working and they're all working. But it can only see what's on top. I dont understand what's missing in here,

```
class StreamDetailController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

   private enum Tabs: Int {
        case mens 
        case women
        case arts
        case saved
    }

    var menImage = [Men]()
    var artsImage = [Arts]()
    var womenImage = [Women]()
    var savedImage = [SavedPhotos]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        guard let tab = Tabs(rawValue: section) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return section
        }

        switch tab {

       case .mens:
          return menImage.count

        case .women:
           return womenImage.count

        case .arts:
            return artsImage.count

        case .saved:
            return savedImage.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let tab = Tabs(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return UICollectionViewCell()
                   }

       switch tab {

      case .mens:

        let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let men =  menImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = men.image
            return cell

        case .women:
            let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let women = womenImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = women.image
            return cell

        case .arts:
            let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let art = artsImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = art.image
            return cell

        case .saved:
            let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let save = savedImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = save.image
            return cell          
        }
      }
```

[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9bay.png)
cases
[Tab Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuKGO.png)

Comment: What's the value of `tab` after assignment?

Comment: Im sorry Alexander, I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: What's the value of the `tab` variable after `guard let tab = ...` and before `switch tab`?

Comment: guard let tab = Tabs(rawValue: section) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return section....
4? I tried to change the "return section" to "return 4" but the problem doesnt change

Comment: enum is not a array

Comment: @Cookingcodes You haven't answered my question

Comment: the value of tab, are the enums, case men, case women, case arts, case saved

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using `section` and not `row` to identify the row. Most likely you only have one section and multiple rows. That's why the section is always zero and points to the first element of your enum. You should change your code to the following:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let tab = Tabs(rawValue: indexPath.row) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return UICollectionViewCell()
                   }

       switch tab {

      case .mens:

        let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let men =  menImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = men.image
            return cell

        case .women:
            let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let women = womenImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = women.image
            return cell

        case .arts:
            let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let art = artsImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = art.image
            return cell

        case .saved:
            let cell = extraCells.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ExtraViewCell
            let save = savedImage[indexPath.item]
            cell.boxImage.image = save.image
            return cell          
        }
      }
```

I have replaced `indexPath.section` with `indexPath.row`

Comment: Had a similar answer drafted up. This should be the solution.

Comment: It's still the same,the pictures of women arts and saved still doesnt show up. :(

Comment: can you print `indexPath` and see what values are coming?

Comment: for men it's [0,0] for the other 3 its nothing, even if I put a error code on womens, it can't identify,

Comment: How many sections do you have in your collectionview? Where do you define that? Can you put some logs printing values of section, indexpath in numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAt delegate?